# Fastest way to find which is the longest string from a set contained in an input string

Tags: c#, string-matching

I have a very large `List<MyClass>` (approximatively 600.000 records +) in which i need to extract the record where `MyClass.Property1` is the exact match or the closest of my input string. However even if it seems it, this is not a fuzzy string matching problem, so i can't use the Levenshtein distance. To clear the things a bit i'll give you an example.

Suppose that the following is my data set (listing only `MyClass.Property1`):

```
242
2421    
2422    
24220   
24221   
24222   
24223   
24224
```

Now what i expect is, if i have in input 2422 i expect the third record to be given in output. If i get in input 24210 i expect in output the second record, which is the longest string contained in my output. To make the things faster, when i fill the `List<MyClass>`, i have saved in a `Dictionary<int,int>` the index at which the first number in the string change (example from 19999 to 20000) so i can reduce the size of the dataset i'm going to search for the match. What i wonder is: Which is the fastest way to reach my goal?

The only thing i can think is something like that:

Since i'm sure that the `List<MyClass>` is ordered by the `MyClass.Property1` like in the example, and supposing that i have extracted a `List<MyClass>` called `SubSet` based on the dictionary i mentioned before, i would do

```
MyClass result = null;
foreach(MyCLass m in SubSet)
{
    if (input.Contains(m.Property1))
    {
       // if the 2 strings are equal i've found the exact match
       if(input == m.Property1)
         return m.Property1;
       else
         result = m;            
    }
    else
       return result;
}
```

The most obvious problem i can see here is the fact that if the desidered result is at the end of the `SubSet` i need to loop over thousands of records Can you think any better way to reach my goal or a way to improve my current code?

Comment: Will this "find" method be called multiple times on the same data? In other words, would you accept a slower "startup" time to make the "find" method faster?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis potentially yes. But it could happen that this method is never called during an instance. To answer, it depends on how much slower is the startup

Answer (score 0):

Maybe,You can use Linq method in recursive function like

```
public string test(string input)
{
    string result = Subset.FirstOrDefault(a => a == input);
    if (result == null)
        return test(input.Substring(0, input.Length - 2));
    else
        return result;
}
```

Comment: I doubt this can be faster than what i did. I'm not sure on how LINQ implement its loop internally but on average you are going to do multiple loop over the same subset against the 1 loop i'm doing currently

Comment: i think ,basically it may be better to use foreach and contains replace firstordefault